# Wordpress Custom post type won't save properly

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types

Note: I first asked this question on stackoverflow but didn't get an answer.

I created a plugin with a new custom post type, it works locally as it should but on one of my websites, which happens to be a multisite, it won't properly save when I add a new custom post item.

When I first try to publish it, it will still save as a draft and the meta box values are not being saved while I am using the save_post hook. Also I am always redirected to /wp-admin/post.php when I save instead of staying on the edit page like it normally does.

This is the custom post type code:

```
public function download_post_type() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Downloads', 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Downloads', 'post type singular name'),
        'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'download'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Download'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Download'),
        'new_item' => __('New Download'),
        'all_items' => __('All Downloads'),
        'view_item' => __('View Download'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Downloads'),
        'not_found' =>  __('No downloads found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No downloads found in Trash'), 
        'parent_item_colon' => '',
        'menu_name' => __('Downloads')
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true, 
        'show_in_menu' => true, 
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/CrystalClear/16x16/apps/ark2.png',  
        'taxonomies' => array( 'category' ), 
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'has_archive' => true, 
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields', 'revisions' )

    ); 
    register_post_type('downloads', $args);
}
```

Comment: Your code looks fine to me. try it only with wordpress default theme and with your plugin making sure other plugins doesn't creating the problem. Also can you share your `save_post`code?

Comment: I confirm. I pasted your code into TwentyTen and everything works as expected.

Comment: Please add [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) and check your server logs if you have access to them.